# VF Page output as text file generation

Tags: apex, visualforce

I CREATED A SAMPLE  VF PAGE , IAM GETTING THE TEXT FILE BUT IT IS IN THE FORM OF CODE:

```
<html>

    <body>

        SMPLE
    </body>

</html><script type="text/javascript">  SfdcApp.Visualforce.viewstate.ViewstateSender.sendViewstate('https://ap2.salesforce.com', 'newtextfile');  </script>
```

THE CODE I WRITTEN:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false"  contentType="text/plain/#emp.txt">
<html>

    <body>

        SMPLE
    </body>

    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to output a text file, just put the text within the apex tags. So without html or body tags:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false"  contentType="text/plain/#emp.txt">
         SMPLE
</apex:page>
```

Comment: i did same thing as  you sent, the code is repeating     
         SMPLE<script type="text/javascript">  SfdcApp.Visualforce.viewstate.ViewstateSender.sendViewstate('https://ap2.salesforce.com', 'vfnotepad');  </script>

Comment: That is usually due to either your user  being in 'development mode' or the developer console being open.  It will work fine for a 'normal' user.

Comment: thank you, suppose in user - page if i click preview on vf page will it be download as text file without code?as of now iam developing text file using vf page preview  , if i click on preview it will  download  text file.

Comment: Yes  I think that will work.

Comment: I believe the second / is in error, though, shouldn't it be "text/plain#emp.txt"?

Comment: @sfdcfox indeed that's the correct syntax. But rajashekar's syntax also worked, when I replicated the issue.  I guess the extra slash is just ignored..